# jQuery buttons to show/hide info and search

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've used multiple tutorials to get the exact look for show/hide using jQuery, but now that I've done it's too repetitive, I've tried to edit it using variables, but it didn't work. Is there a way to avoid repetitiveness here?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).click(function(event) {
    if ($(event.target).is(".info-icon") || $(event.target).is(".info-tab") || ($(".info-tab").has(event.target).length == 1)) {
      if ($(".info-tab").height() != 0 && !$(event.target).is(".info-tab") && !($(".info-tab").has(event.target).length == 1)) {
        $(".info-tab").css("max-height", "0");
      } else {
        if ($(".search-tab").height() != 0) {
          $(".search-tab").css("max-height", "0");
          setTimeout(function() {
            $(".info-tab").css("max-height", "200px");
          }, 300);
        } else {
          $(".info-tab").css("max-height", "200px");
        }
      }
    } else if ($(event.target).is(".search-icon") || $(event.target).is(".search-tab") || ($(".search-tab").has(event.target).length == 1)) {
      if ($(".search-tab").height() != 0 && !$(event.target).is(".search-tab") && !($(".search-tab").has(event.target).length == 1)) {
        $(".search-tab").css("max-height", "0");
      } else {
        if ($(".info-tab").height() != 0) {
          $(".info-tab").css("max-height", "0");
          setTimeout(function() {
            $(".search-tab").css("max-height", "200px");
          }, 300);
        } else {
          $(".search-tab").css("max-height", "200px");
        }
      }
    } else {
      $(".info-tab").css("max-height", "0");
      $(".search-tab").css("max-height", "0");
    }
  });
});
```

JSFiddle for what it does is here: https://jsfiddle.net/msms92/L9L0tqvp/

Answer (score 2):

The first thing that comes to my mind is that what you're trying to do is handling *all* of the `click` events in just *one handler function!* Don't!

Use delegate event listeners instead:

```
$(document)
    .on("click", ".info-icon, .info-tab", function(e) {
       e.stopPropagation();
       // Deal with .info-icon or .info-tab
    })
    .on("click", ".search-icon, .search-tab", function(e) {
       e.stopPropagation();
       // Deal with .search-icon or .search-tab
    })
    .on("click", function(e) {
       // Other clicks
    });
```

Secondarily, define CSS classes list `.info-tab-open` and `.search-tab-open` like these:

```
.info-tab-open {
    max-height: 200px;
}
```

(And remember: using magic numbers is *bad*, especially when styling with JavaScript.)

So you'll end up doing this instead:

```
var $infoTab = $(".info-tab");
if ($infoTab.hasClass("info-tab-open")) {
    $infoTab.removeClass("info-tab-open");
} else {
    var $searchTab = $(".search-tab");
    if ($searchTab.hasClass("search-tab-open")) {
        $searchTab.removeClass("search-tab-open");
        setTimeout(..., 300);
    } else {
        $infoTab.addClass("info-tab-open");
    }
}
```

Third: since the handler's code is basically the same and repeating code is a code smell, you'll probably be better off if you use a factory function for the handler:

```
function toggler(selectedClass, otherClass) {
    return function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        var $selectedTab = $("." + selectedClass);
        if ($selectedTab.hasClass(selectedClass + "-open")) {
            $selectedTab.removeClass(selectedClass + "-open");
        } else {
            var $otherTab = $("." + otherClass);
            if ($otherTab.hasClass(otherClass + "-open")) {
                $otherTab.removeClass(otherClass + "-open");
                setTimeout(..., 300);
            } else {
                $selectedTab.addClass(selectedClass + "-open");
            }
        }
    };
}

$(document)
    .on("click", ".info-icon, .info-tab", toggler("info-tab", "search-tab"))
    .on("click", ".search-icon, .search-tab", toggler("search-tab", "info-tab"))
    .on("click", function() {
        $(".info-tab").removeClass("info-tab-open");
        $(".search-tab").removeClass("search-tab-open");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

WTF?

Why not just select the block you want with $("CSS _Selector") and use the .show() or .hide() method.

Comment: Because I don't want to. It's also not gonna help me avoid repeating the code for each button/tab.

Comment: Take at look at my updated fiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/L9L0tqvp/1/

Comment: Okay, it's not exactly what I need, it doesn't hide the other "data-target" when clicked on the second one, but I might get it to work.

Comment: Just add a $(".info-wrapper").hide() before the toggle.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the **.css** method.  Create CSS classes and use the class rules to update the display with **.addClass** and **.removeClass**, or **.toggle**

Comment: I tried, .css part isn't the problem. It's the same code for each button/tab, I want to get rid off.

Comment: @MSmS It *is* part of the problem. Your code looks *messy* to begin with. If you embrace JavaScript's and jQuery's best practices, the solution will come naturally.